# Обновление wordpress сломало главное меню

Tags: php, wordpress

После обновления wordpress до последней версии сломалось верхнее меню - пункты меню не отображаются.

В консоли такие ошибки (404):

`http://site.ru/wp-content/plugins/rti-slider/inc/functions.js?ver=4.7.2`
`http://site.ru/wp-content/plugins/rti-slider/inc/rtislider.css?ver=4.7.2`

и т.д.

Кто сталкивался с подобным, в чем м.б. проблема?

P.S. Почему в пути до файла указана версия WP `ver=4.7.2`? Это может как-то повлиять?

**UPD**

Меню выводится так:

```
<?php
        $walker = new mainMenuWalker ();
        $args = array(
            'theme_location'  => '',
            'menu'            => 2,
            'container'       => false,
            'menu_class'      => nav,
            'menu_id'         => '',
            'echo'            => true,
            'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
            'before'          => '',
            'after'           => '',
            'link_before'     => '',
            'link_after'      => '',
            'items_wrap'      => '<ul class="nav navbar-nav">%3$s</ul>',
            'depth'           => 0,
            'walker' => $walker
        );
        //wp_nav_menu( $args );

        wp_nav_menu( array(
                'menu' => 2,
                'depth' => 2,
                'container' => false,
                'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav',
                //Process nav menu using our custom nav walker
                'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
        );
        ?>
```

Может тут ошибка?

**UPD**

Дебаг выводит такие ошибки:

`Notice: Use of undefined constant nav - assumed 'nav' in /home/g/genomq/site.ru/public_html/wp-content/themes/rti/header.php on line 76`

`Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/g/genomq/site.ru/public_html/wp-content/themes/rti/include/wp-bootstrap-nav.php on line 65`

Answer (score 0):

> в чем м.б. проблема?

В отсутствии файлов плагина `/wp-content/plugins/rti-slider/inc/functions.js` `/wp-content/plugins/rti-slider/inc/rtislider.css`

Однако вряд ли слайдер будет виноват в "поломке" меню.

> Почему в пути до файла указана версия WP ver=4.7.2? Это может как-то повлиять?

В нормальном случает не может. Только если какие-то неправильные защиты/редректы где-то прописаны.

Answer (score 0):

wp_debug пробовали? Скорее проблема в том, что wordpress обновился, изменились какие-то хуки, например, а плагин был написан под старые, поэтому сейчас ошибка, как вариант.